# Limit point of the graph of a set valued function.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb R^n\to 2^{\mathbb R^m}$ a set valued function. Let $$\Gamma =\{(x,F(x))\mid x\in \mathbb R^n\},$$
its graph. I'm reading a book where they take $(p,q)$ a limit point of $\Gamma $ and they say that this implies that there are sequences $p_i\to p\in \mathbb R^n$, $q_i\to q$, where $q_i\in F(p_i)$.

**Question** What is strange it's that $q$ is a set whereas $q_i$ are element of $\mathbb R^m$, so what mean $q_i\to q$ ? Don't they want to say that there is a sequence $p_i\to p\in\mathbb R^n$ s.t. $F(p_i)\to q$ ? But I'm not so sure what mean $F(p_i)\to q$. Should it be that $q=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}F(p_i)$.

---

For reference, this appear in chapter 2, proof of lemma 14, $\S$5 (page 66) of "Differential equation with continuous righthand sides" of A.F. Filipov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 65 the author of the book you mentioned defines the graph of $F$ as 
$$ \{(p,q) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m  \:|\: p \in D, q \in F(p)\} $$
and given this definition of graph of a set-valued function the statement is just about convergence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: Just by cuiriosity, don't we have $$\{(p,q)\mid p\in D, q\in F(p)\}=\{\{p\}\times F(p)\mid p\in D\}\ \ ?$$

Comment: Actually, it is $$ \bigcup_{p \in D} \{p\} \times F(p). $$